# Converting an array into JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, csv

I need to bring in a csv doc and convert it to JSON, so far I have been able to convert it to an array and from the array I'm trying to build a JSON object.

Below is the JavaScript that builds the JSON, but its not in the structure I need, underneath is an example of the structure required.

```
var jsonObj = []; //declare object

for (var i=1;i<csvAsArray.length;i++) { 
  jsonObj.push({key: csvAsArray[i][0]}); //key

    for (var l=1;l<csvAsArray[0].length;l++) { 
      jsonObj.push({label: csvAsArray[0][l], values: csvAsArray[i][l]}); //label + value respectively
    }
}
```

Final output required:

```
{
  "key": "Sample 01",
  "values": [
    { 
      "label" : "Something" ,
      "value" : 1
    } , 
    { 
      "label" : "Something" ,
      "value" : 2
    }
  ]
},
{
  "key": "Sample 02",
  "values": [
    { 
      "label" : "Something" ,
      "value" : 5
    } , 
    { 
      "label" : "Something" ,
      "value" : 4
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Why not just use `JSON.stringify()`?

Comment: So, your problem is to structure the data properly, not how to convert it to JSON? Please be clear about the issue.

Comment: What does the current array look like?

Comment: Post an example of the CSV file from which you'd like to generate that output.  Also I assume there's an outer `[]` missing in your output example, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to declare the values and push that onto a tmp variable before pushing that index onto the final/main object

```
var tmp_values, jsonObj = []; //declare object

for (var i=1;i<csvAsArray.length;i++) {
    var tmp_values = [];
    for (var l=1;l<csvAsArray[0].length;l++) { 
        tmp_values.push({label: csvAsArray[0][l], value: csvAsArray[i][l]}); //label + value respectively
    }
    jsonObj.push({key: csvAsArray[i][0], values: tmp_values}); //key
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Simply use `JSON.stringify()` to convert your array to json string

```
var jsonString = JSON.stringify(yourArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

This [script](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js) is a common way to convert an array to JSON in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a fan of answers like this, but [this service](http://shancarter.github.io/mr-data-converter/) in my opinion is good enough to warrant it. It can convert between various data formats including CSV, JSON, XML, HTML table, etc. It even offers variations in output structure for some of the formats.

- http://shancarter.github.io/mr-data-converter/

Answer (score 0):

use this code and very simple develop for more two array

```
function getJSON(arrayID,arrayText) {    
    var JSON = "[";
    //should arrayID length equal arrayText lenght and both against null
    if (arrayID != null && arrayText != null && arrayID.length == arrayText.length) {
        for (var i = 0; i < arrayID.length; i++) {
            JSON += "{";
            JSON += "text:'" + arrayText[i] + "',";
            JSON += "id:'" + arrayID[i] + "'";
            JSON += "},";
        }
    }
    JSON += "]"
    JSON = Function("return " + JSON + " ;");
    return JSON();
}
```

and 3 array

```
function getJSON(arrayID, arrayText, arrayNumber) {
    var JSON = "[";  
    if (arrayID != null && arrayText != null && arrayNumber!=null && Math.min(arrayNumber.length,arrayID.length)==arrayText.length) {
        for (var i = 0; i < arrayID.length; i++) {
            JSON += "{";
            JSON += "text:'" + arrayText[i] + "',";
            JSON += "id:'" + arrayID[i] + "',";
            JSON += "number:'" + arrayNumber[i] + "'";
            JSON += "},";
        }
    }
    JSON += "]"
    JSON = Function("return " + JSON + " ;");
    return JSON();
}
```

Comment: Never use your own serialization functions, please use `JSON.stringify()`.

Comment: just JSON.stringify()? no other solution

Comment: About serialization, no. About restructuring your data you have to write your own logic of course ^^