# Converting array into a JS Object

Tags: javascript

I have key value pairs in an array in the format -

```
["model:B250W,C300W4,E300W4,GLA250W4", "class:E", "exteriorColor:BLK", "interiorColor:BGE", "price:30000,115000", "year:2018", "bodyStyle:SDN,CPE,SUV"].
```

How can I convert this into a JS object? The expected output should be:

```
{
    "model":"B250W,C300W4,E300W4,GLA250W4",
    "class":"E",
    "exteriorColor":"BLK",
    "interiorColor":"BGE", 
    "price":"30000,115000", 
    "year":"2018", 
    "bodyStyle":"SDN,CPE,SUV"
}
```

I tried-

```
y=["model:B250W,C300W4,E300W4,GLA250W4", "class:E", "exteriorColor:BLK", "interiorColor:BGE", "price:30000,115000", "year:2018", "bodyStyle:SDN,CPE,SUV"];
x=Object();
x.y[0].split('&')[0]=y[0].split('&')[1];
```

But I'm getting an error. Is this some other way to assign key and values to an object?

Comment: Now would be a good time to reread [ask] and provide a [mcve] and a properly formatted question.

Comment: JSON.stringify() ?

Comment: Do you mean a JS object, or JSON?  JSON is not an object, it is a string.  What exactly is your desired result, and what code do you have so far?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting an array into JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19262738/converting-an-array-into-json)

Comment: @Kosmos I think the OP wants JSON.parse(strValue); (depends on answer to Amy)

Comment: What are the _keys_ and what are the _values_ (_I have key value pairs_)

Comment: @RandyCasburn My guess was that each string is a key/value pair separated by a colon.  However, the second string contains two colons.  :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could iterate the strings, split the values and take the first item as key and join all other values (if splitted) for a new object.

At the end create a single object.

```js
var data = ["model:B250W,C300W4,E300W4,GLA250W4", "class:E", "exteriorColor:BLK", "interiorColor:BGE", "price:30000,115000", "year:2018", "bodyStyle:SDN,CPE,SUV"],
    object = Object.assign(
        ...data.map(s => (([k, ...v]) => ({ [k]: v.join(':') }))(s.split(':')))
    );
    
console.log(object);
```

Answer (score 0):

@Nina's answer is great. Just another solution with [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) if you wish to try

```
var arr = ["model:B250W,C300W4,E300W4,GLA250W4", "class:E", "exteriorColor:BLK", "interiorColor:BGE", "price:30000,115000", "year:2018", "bodyStyle:SDN,CPE,SUV"]

arr.reduce((obj, d) => (obj[d.split(':')[0]] = d.split(':')[1], obj), {})
```