# Convert an array of objects into an array with key values

Tags: javascript, arrays

How to convert an array of objects into an array with keys and values. We are sure to each object contain only one value.

```
"values":[
    {
        "first(%)":"91.52%"
    },
    {
        "second(%)":"98.98%"
    },
    {
        "Total(%)":"95.00%"
    }
]
```

Desired output:

```
"values":[
    "first(%)":"91.52%",
    "second(%)":"98.98%",
    "Total(%)":"95.00%",
]
```

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have associative arrays, FYI

Comment: Sorry my bad, I mean JSON using JS.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting an array into JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19262738/converting-an-array-into-json)

Comment: And that wouldn't be valid json either. You probably want something like `{"values" : {"first(%)": "91.52%", ...}`

Answer (score 4):

You could assign all objects to a single object by taking [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign).

```js
var object = { values: [{ "first(%)": "91.52%" }, { "second(%)": "98.98%" }, { "Total(%)": "95.00%" }] },
    result = { values: Object.assign({}, ...object.values) };
    
console.log(result);
```

Comment: better `Object.assign({}, ...object.values)` or you'll mutate `object.values[0]`

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to put each object in your values array into the new accumulated object like so:

```js
const values=[{"first(%)":"91.52%"},{"second(%)":"98.98%"},{"Total(%)":"95.00%"}],

valObj = values.reduce((acc, obj) => ({...acc, ...obj}), {});
console.log(valObj);
```

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript does not have associative arrays. However you can use objects to store key/values.

Here is a way to extract the key/values from the items in the array and set them on an object using [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```js
const data = {
  "values": [
    { "first(%)":"91.52%"},
    { "second(%)":"98.98%" },
    { "Total(%)":"95.00%" }
  ]
};

const result = data.values.reduce((acc, x) => {
  Object.entries(x).forEach(([key, val]) => acc[key] = val);
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

In javascript, you can use `Object.assign` to store the object in key/value pair because JavaScript does not Support associative arrays.
You can use it as an object.

```
 const data = { values: 
              [{ "first(%)": "91.52%" },
               { "second(%)": "98.98%" },
               { "Total(%)": "95.00%" }] };

 const result = { values: Object.assign({}, ...data.values) };

console.log("result",result);
```

Comment: Thank you, Khyati!